# how to 'call' (refer to) a dataframe using character element "i" in another dataframe

Tags: r, parsing, text

I have 3 DF:

1. "CAR" with 100 rows and 2 columns
2. "BIKE" with 60 rows and 3 columns
3. "ELENCO_DF" with 2 rows and 1 column

ELENCO_DF is like that

**Nome**
CAR
BIKE

Each element rappresent the "name" of the other DF

```
#for each element of ELENCO_DF I would like to print the following

for (i in 1:nrow(ELENCO_DF)){
    print(nrow(ELENCO_DF[i]))
}

#Thanks a lot in advance
```

Comment: It's difficult to offer help without the data.  One solution with multiple data.frames is to first join them, e.g. using `full_join()`.  Then it's often easy to filter and print those you want.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not so expert. I try to explain better: ELENCO_DF[1] is "CAR" so if I would need to print nrow(CAR) using "CAR" it do not works

Comment: my final goal is to create a DF that contains 2 columns one of which is the list of all the variables of my environment and the second the type of variable type (integer, character, data.frame ...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i do not have code...I have to write it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(ELENCO_DF)){
     print(nrow(get(ELENCO_DF[i,])))
}
```

With the "get" function in R you `parse` and `eval`-uate the strings "CAR" or "BIKE" which up to that point were only character values not associated with any R objects. You are then able to access the dataframe objects in the symbol table, and apply the usual extraction or modification functions to those objects.

You may read more about it by writing the command

```
?get
```

in the R console of your choice. It's not actually "call"-ing the objects since the term "call" in R terminology is reserved for a step along the way to executing an R function. See `call` for information about that language feature.

Comment: Instead of answering for a second time, you should have edited the first answer, correcting what is wrong with it.